# Amazon S3 get version id of object on upload

Tags: php, api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I enabled versioning in my bucket to prevent overwriting files with the same name. When I create an object in my php app I need to store the version id in my database to use when deleting the object.

I'm currently getting the version id from the returned header response from uploading

```
//upload the file           
$response = $s3->create_object($bucket, $filename, array(
    'fileUpload' => $filepath,
    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
    'contentType' => $this->upload->file_type,
    'storage'     => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,         
));

//get version id 
$version_id' => $response->header['x-amz-version-id'];
```

Is this the correct way to do it? I need to use version ids when deleting objects and need to save the version ids of corresponding objects in the db when uploading. I would really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping version id in you data base, you can get back again that version id from version listing for the given prefix as well as for object. That will return you all version for the given object. which marker that which one is latest and which one is delete etc.

I am from development team of Bucket Explorer, you can check the listing using it.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I'm just starting with S3. I don't know the full potential of version ids. I'm keeping information in my db about all the objects I upload. I use the db information when I'm deleting objects. When I delete an object I already have the version id in my database so I'm not making a new request to get it. (I'm not sure how I would get the corresponding version id in php if say more objects have the same name) For this reason I have to get the version id on upload.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is the most efficient way to grab the version ID on an upload.

I'm still a little unclear on your reasons for storing the version IDs for an object version in a database when S3 already does this for you. By calling [AmazonS3::list_bucket_object_versions()](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/list_bucket_object_versions) and passing a `prefix` value to specifically target a single object in the bucket, S3 will return a list of all corresponding version IDs for that object.

I hope this helps! :)